# Wordpress lazy Loading with just HTML - Loading more images than it should

Tags: lazy-loading

I never have an issue with lazy loading using my code editor, it usually just loads the next image when I scroll. This time I need to do it in WordPress without using a plugin. So I just added  `loading="lazy` in my `<img>` tag. However, when I test the lazy loading in the network tool, it loaded 4 images when there are only 1 and a half images showing on the screen. It's even worse for the smaller screen, it loaded 8 images when there are only 3 images in the viewpoint. How can I make it only load the following image?

[image: large screen]
[image: small screen]

I tried adding `margin` to the bottom of the image, it reduced from loading 6 to loading 4 images for the large screen. However, it would not look good with big gaps between images.

Comment: Images are downloaded before they are visible, to ensure that they have loaded when they are visible. According to the article, in Chromium the margin is currently 2500px in the worst case, and could be 4000px in old versions. https://web.dev/browser-level-image-lazy-loading/#distance-from-viewport-thresholds

Answer (score 0):

When the browser loads an image, it will not immediately recognize the size of the image unless it is explicitly specified. To allow the browser to reserve enough space on the page for images, it is recommended that all `<img>` tags include `width` and `height` attributes. Without the dimensions included, layout shifts may occur that are more noticeable on pages that take longer to load.

In most scenarios, delayed image loading applies even if no image dimensions are specified, but there are a few non-standard situations that you should be aware of. Without `width` and `height` specified, the image dimensions are initially 0×0 pixels. If you have a gallery of such images, the browser may decide that they all initially fit in the viewing area because they take up almost no space and are not pushed out of the screen. In this case, the browser determines that they are all visible to the user and decides to load the images.